# Godot repeating breaks script

Tags: loops, godot, gdscript

I'm making a mode 7/perspective projection project in Godot. When I run it, it produces the expected effect, displaying a 2d image as if it were a 3d plane.
Code:

```
func _ready():
map.load("res://map2.png")
perspective.load("res://map2.png")
for px in 1:
    self.texture = display
    for y in map.get_height():
        _y = (y + py - 1)/z
        for x in map.get_width():
            _x = (x + px)/z
            map.lock()
            pix = map.get_pixel(_x, _y)
            map.unlock()
            perspective.lock()
            perspective.set_pixel(x, y, pix)
            perspective.unlock()
        display.create_from_image(perspective)
        z += 1
```

Image:

[image]

However, I have a problem. I have the code in the ready function, in a for loop. I want it to be called every frame, but when I increase the number of repeats from one to two, it turns the entire image red. I don't know what's causing this. one guess was that I wasn't locking and unlocking the images properly, but that is most likely not the case. Another guess was that the x and y variables were not resetting each time, but that was also working fine. I don't think the loop itself is the problem, but I have no idea what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled to make your code run. I half way gave up, and implemented the logic from [my prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67271427/simple-mode-7-formula-example) using lock bits instead. This is the code:

```
extends Sprite

export(Transform) var matrix:Transform
var sampler:Image
var buffer:Image
var size:Vector2
var center:Vector2

func _ready():
    sampler = texture.get_data()
    var err = sampler.decompress()
    if err != OK:
        push_error("Failed to decompress texture")
        return

    size = Vector2(texture.get_width(), texture.get_height())
    center = size * 0.5

    buffer = Image.new()
    buffer.create(int(size.x), int(size.y), false, Image.FORMAT_RGBA8)

func _process(_delta):
    #matrix = matrix.rotated(Vector3.RIGHT, 0.01)
    
    sampler.lock()
    buffer.lock()
    for y in size.x:
        for x in size.y:
            var uv:Vector3 = matrix * Vector3(x - center.x, y - center.y, 1.0)
            
            if uv.z <= 0.0:
                buffer.set_pixel(x, y, Color.transparent)
                continue
            
            var _x = (uv.x / uv.z) + center.x
            var _y = (uv.y / uv.z) + center.y
            if _x < 0.0 or _x >= size.x or _y < 0.0 or _y >= size.y:
                buffer.set_pixel(x, y, Color.transparent)
                continue

            #buffer.set_pixel(x, y, Color(_x / size.x, y / size.y, 0.0))
            buffer.set_pixel(x, y, sampler.get_pixel(_x, _y))
    buffer.unlock()
    sampler.unlock()

    var display = ImageTexture.new()
    display.create_from_image(buffer, 0)
    self.texture = display
```

As you can see, I'm exporting a `Transfrom` to be available on the editor. That is a proper 3D Transform. There is a commented line on `_process` that does a rotation, try it out.

The `sampler` `Image` is a copy of the `Texture` of the `Sprite` (the copy is made on `_ready`). And the `buffer` `Image` is where what is to be displayed is constructed.

The code is creating an `ImageTexture` from `buffer` and replacing the current `texture` with it, each frame (on `_process`). I'm setting flags to `0`, because `FLAG_REPEAT` plus `FLAG_FILTER` blurred the border to the opposite side of the `Sprite`.

The vector `Vector2` `size` holds the size of the texture. And the `Vector2` `Center` is the coordinates of the center.

---

As I said at the start, this is the logic from my prior answer. This line:

```
vec3 uv = matrix * vec3(UV - 0.5, 1.0);
```

Is equivalent to (except I'm not scaling the coordinates to the range from 0 to 1):

```
var uv:Vector3 = matrix * Vector3(x - center.x, y - center.y, 1.0)
```

Then I had this line:

```
if (uv.z < 0.0) discard;
```

Which turned out like this:

```
if uv.z <= 0.0:
    buffer.set_pixel(x, y, Color.transparent)
    continue
```

I'm setting transparent because I do not recreate the buffer, nor clear it before hand.

Finally this line:

```
COLOR = texture(TEXTURE, (uv.xy / uv.z) + 0.5);
```

Turned out like this:

```
var _x = (uv.x / uv.z) + center.x
var _y = (uv.y / uv.z) + center.y
if _x < 0.0 or _x >= size.x or _y < 0.0 or _y >= size.y:
    buffer.set_pixel(x, y, Color.transparent)
    continue

buffer.set_pixel(x, y, sampler.get_pixel(_x, _y))
```

---

As per the result, here is the Godot Icon "rotating in 3D" (not really, but that is the idea):

[image: Result]

*Please disregard visual artifact due to GIF encoding.*

I'm not sure if you want to stay with the logic of my prior answer. However, I believe this one should not be too hard to modify for your needs.

---

### Addendum

I used a Transform because there is no convenient Matrix type available. However, the Transform uses a Matrix internally. See also [Transformation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix).

The [Mode 7 formula according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_7#Formula) works with a 2 by 2 Matrix, which is simpler that what I have here. However, you are going to need the product of a Matrix and a Vector anyway. You cannot compute the components independently.

This is the formula according to Wikipedia:

```
r' = M*(r - r_0) + r_0
```

That is:

```
var rp = mult(M, r - r_0) + r_0
```

Where `mult` would look like this:

```
func mult(matrix, vector:Vector2) -> Vector2:
    var x = vector.x * matrix.a + vector.y * matrix.b
    var y = vector.x * matrix.c + vector.y * matrix.d
    return Vector2(x, y)
```

However, as I said, there is no convenient matrix type. If we export `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`, we have:

```
var rp = mult(a, b, c, d, r - r_0) + r_0
```

And `mult` looks like this:

```
func mult(a:float, b:float, c:float, d:float, vector:Vector2) -> Vector2:
    var x = vector.x * a + vector.y * b
    var y = vector.x * c + vector.y * d
    return Vector2(x, y)
```

---

We can easily use modify the code to do that. First export `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` as I said:

```
export(float) var a:float
export(float) var b:float
export(float) var c:float
export(float) var d:float
```

And this is `_process` modified:

```
func _process(_delta):
    sampler.lock()
    buffer.lock()
    for y in size.x:
        for x in size.y:
            var rp = mult(a, b, c, d, Vector2(x, y) - center) + center
            if rp.x < 0.0 or rp.x >= size.x or rp.y < 0.0 or rp.y >= size.y:
                buffer.set_pixel(x, y, Color.transparent)
                continue

            buffer.set_pixel(x, y, sampler.get_pixel(rp.x, rp.y))
    buffer.unlock()
    sampler.unlock()

    var display = ImageTexture.new()
    display.create_from_image(buffer, 6)
    self.texture = display
```

Of course, `mult` is the one I showed above. *I'm assuming here that `r_0` is what I called `center`.*

I'm not sure how to interpret `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, so here is `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 3` and `d = 4`:

[image: Godot Icon stretched and skewed]