# Can you hide a node when not directly above a parent in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

So I have an instanced scene that is supposed to be the child of a colour rect in my tree. I want to randomly generate the nodes, but I also want parts of the view to be cut off if the texture no longer is above the main section. I know you can render nodes below their parents, but I don't know if stopping part of them from rendering is physically possible.

[In this image I want the bottom circle to remain the same, but the top circle to not show anything above the dark purple box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6wY3.png)

[This is the node tree in the editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l67qn.png)

Is there any way to do this directly, or am I gonna have to use a viewport of some variety?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is to set [`rect_clip_content`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_control.html#class-control-property-rect-clip-content) to `true` on the `ColorRect` (or whatever `Control`). Making invisible any part of its children outside of it.

From Godot's documentation:

> bool rect_clip_content
>
> Enables whether rendering of CanvasItem based children should be clipped to this control's rectangle. If true, parts of a child which would be visibly outside of this control's rectangle will not be rendered.

---

If what you want is the opposite, perhaps you can use `z_index` to have something render on top, occluding the parts you don't want visible.

---

There is also a trick you can use with lights (including 2D lights):

- Make a light that matches the area you want things to be visible.
- Set a custom material that will be transparent by default, but visible on the light pass. The simpler way to do this is to set the `light_mode` of the material to "Light Only". *You could also do it with a custom shader instead.*

---

Making something disappear with light, in 2D, is impossible. *In 3D, you can use `flags_use_shadow_to_opacity`. That is how you make a shadow catcher.*

But, there is one more trick: you can use a mask. This should give you full control of when to show or hide things. So, if none of the above solutions works for you, use a mask. I have an explanation in [a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69916438/402022). See also: [How to crop sprite in a non-rectangular form?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71491761/402022).

---

Mighty Mochi Games recently (2022-03-30) made a compilation of the different approaches in video form: [Mask Methods Collection - Godot 3.x - 2D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wWjICXOOd00)
.