# How to create specific dark regions which can be illuminated by Light2D?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I have my game normally setup as such:
[image]

and I'm trying to create "specific" dark regions within the game as such:

[image]

so that whenever a light source is present it would "light up" the view by making the `ColorRect` transparent within the texture provided to the light2D (a photoshoped image of what I'm trying to achieve) :
[image]

I tried [this demo](https://godotengine.org/asset-library/asset/115) but it only lights up the image instead of making it transparent

I also tried [this demo](https://www.gdquest.com/tutorial/godot/2d/limiting-vision-with-lights/) but it seems to apply to the entire game instead of a particular region and I would have to change the properties of all objects entirely throughout the game

Is what I'm trying to achieve possible? Or is there a alternate approach I should be taking altogether?

---

**Note, you might ask:**

*"Why don't you just add a shader to the ColorRect to make the desired region transparent?"*

Because there are multiple light sources and it wouldn't be possible to tally them all and add them into a shader

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GODOT How can I xray through tilemaps around me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911347/godot-how-can-i-xray-through-tilemaps-around-me)

Comment: @Theraot Feels a bit overkill, could you check the solution I've posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nvm I figured it out

First, Make a `CanvasLayer` node and set it to the same layer you're working on (0 in my case) and check `follow_viewport_enable`:

[image]

Then add a `CanvasModulate` node and set it's `color` to black (or whatever you desire):
[image]

[image]

Then add a `ColorRect` and add the shader code given below to it:
[image]

```
shader_type canvas_item;

uniform float position : hint_range(-0.5, 0.5) = 0.0;
uniform float size : hint_range(0.5, 2) = 0.5;
uniform float angle : hint_range(0.0, 360.0) = 0.0;

void fragment() {
    float pivot = position + 0.5;
    vec2 uv = UV - pivot;
    float pos = smoothstep((1.0 - size) + position, size + 0.0001 + position, uv.x + pivot);
    COLOR = texture(SCREEN_TEXTURE, SCREEN_UV);
    COLOR.a=1.0-pos; 
}

void light(){
    if(LIGHT.a!=0.0 && COLOR.a!=0.0)
        LIGHT.a/= COLOR.a;
}
```

Now add Lights (with `mode` set to Mix) and see it in action!

[image]

and if the overlapping lights looks weird in the editor then don't worry it looks perfectly fine when running the game:
[image]

**Edit:** Fixed darkness gradient overlapping with light